# Curl -d command from the terminal

Tags: xml, curl

I had a specific question in regards to curl. I want to call my xml page and  I am executing something like this from my terminal:

```
curl -d @<xml page> <url>
```

However when i execute the following command, i get the following:

```
Invalid request structure
```

In my xml page request is as follows:

```
<example type="request">
            <doLogin>
                    <userName>my_username</userName>
                    <password>my_password</password>
                    <...other details>
            </doLogin>
</example>
```

How do i pass the parameters for username and password in the curl command?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to post a `XML` file, try doing this :

```
curl -d "@./file.xml" -X POST -H 'Content-Type:text/xml' http://domain.tld/path
```

If instead the username/password is handled by *basic auth*, try doing this using an *unix shell*:

```
user=$(xmllint --xpath '/example/doLogin/userName/text()' file.xml)
pass=$(xmllint --xpath '/example/doLogin/password/text()' file.xml)
curl -u "$user:$pass" http://domain.tld/path
```

`XML` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<example type="request">
            <doLogin>
                    <userName>my_username</userName>
                    <password>my_password</password>
                    <...other details>
            </doLogin>
</example>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how you can send that XML file with a POST and yet have your custom user and password get used within that XML, all from a single command line?

If so, then piping the template XML file through sed to letting it fill in the correct values could be an idea, and then let curl read the file to post from its stdin.

> $ sed -e "s/my_username/$user/g" -e "s/my_password/$password/g" < template_file | curl -d@- [URL]